# How do I stream a large file from api to api without using disk and running out of memory?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a API HTTPGET that retrieves a file from another API, and spits it out. This works for smaller files, but the problem I'm having is that the files retrieved can be rather large in size (up to 2gb), and the MemoryStream is a limitation. Any ideas how to stream the file content without using disk and avoiding the 'out of memory' exception?

Controller:

```
[Route("{id}/file", Name = "GetContentFile")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetContentFile(string id)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        return BadRequest();
    ContentFile cfl = new ContentFile();
    var ret = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    try
    {
        cfl = otcrepo.GetContentFile(id);
        var mstream = new MemoryStream(cfl.Data);
        ret.Content = new StreamContent(mstream);
        ret.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(cfl.ContentType);
        ret.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    }
    catch
    {
        return InternalServerError();
    }
    if (cfl != null)
    {
        ResponseMessageResult responseMessageResult = ResponseMessage(ret);
        return responseMessageResult;
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class ContentFile
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public StreamContent DataStream { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

Repository call:

```
public ContentFile GetContentFile(string id)
{
    ContentFile fl = new ContentFile();
    using (var htc = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = htc.GetAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"] + "/api/v2/nodes/" + id + "/content/").Result;

        fl.Data = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
        fl.ContentType = response.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return fl;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: without using memory?

Comment: If you aren't willing to use memory **or** disk, I can't see how this is possible. What is the other alternative (than memory or disk)?

Comment: I'll rephrase my question, since as you point out, some memory must be used. How to do it while avoiding the outofmemoryexception?

Comment: I'd suggest you likely need to store it on disk. Is that an option?

Comment: Whoa, hold on a minute here, you have other problems to worry about.  **You are using `.Result` on an asynchronous task**.  That is incredibly dangerous! This can deadlock your server. It's asynchronous for a reason; you have to `await` that. Get your code right before you attempt to get it fast.

Comment: That aside, I do not understand why you are doing what you are doing. You say you don't want to put the file in memory, but you are reading it into memory as a byte array. If you want to stream it then why are you moving it into a byte array, and then putting a stream on top of the byte array? That is a very strange thing to do.  Why are you not just calling `GetResponseStream` ? You want a stream, well, get a stream. Don't get a byte array and build a stream on top of it.

Comment: You have an array to store the `data[]` in but that array will give you an out-of-memory exception, regardless of how you read it in. You should be writing this in chunks to a file via the response stream and then when you need to use it, use Memory Mapped Files. The `MemoryStream` isn't the limitation, it is the process space.

Comment: If you could stream it directly to the other servers input, you might minimize the memory footprint. That might require you to undo a bunch of the code that is doing work for you however. Also a danger here is that this might trigger some "Slow Lorris" defense code if the source is delivering too slow (and thus the sendon is to slow): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiFkyR35v2Y

Comment: You can try to split the file in byte array & then pass it to API. Alternatively, store the file in cloud e.g. Azure blob storage & then pass URI to the APIs.

Comment: "Get your code right before you attempt to get it fast." - I know this code isn't right. That's why I'm here asking for help. The byte array doesn't have to be there. I just used it because it worked for smaller files. How do I stream the content from the repository API call to the response? Hope this clarifies my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of `GetContentFile` reading the complete stream into an array and returning it we return the stream. Than there is no need for the `MemoryStream`.

```
[Route("{id}/file", Name = "GetContentFile")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetContentFile(string id)
{
    ...
    var result = await otcrepo.GetContentFile(id);
    ret.Content = new StreamContent(result.stream);
    ret.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(result.contentType);
    ...

}

public async Task<(Stream stream, string contentType)> GetContentFile(string id)
{
    var htc = new HttpClient()
    var response = await htc.GetAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"] + "/api/v2/nodes/" + id + "/content/");

    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var contentType = response.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").FirstOrDefault();
    return (stream, contentType);
}
```